# How to render gummy - jelly like movement in character

Tags: rendering, rigid-body-simulation

I want to render an animation of character which is a bit jelly like. You know, it has that lulling like movement when its moving around.

Sometimes you see that in games when fat character walks there is this bouncy, lully movement on its torso.

Any ideas how to do it?
Maybe fluid simulator?

The idea is to have this effect a little bit , but not overdo it.

Comment: probably more soft bodies than fluid simulation...

Comment: yes soft bodies seems promising